# How to provide an environment to the script which is loaded via `loadfile`?

Tags: lua

I am creating a game with love-2d framework and I want to provide a steam workshop items (third-party scenarios). Love2D provides a good interface but it is very bad if I want to supply third-party scenarios with that interface because then they can do everything with it. So I decided to encapsulate love2D by providing custom functions like this:

```
function MyMenu:scenario()
    local game = {
        draw = {
            circle = love.graphics.circle
        },
        timer = {
            sleep = love.timer.sleep
        },
    }
    local scenario = love.filesystem.load("scenario.lua")
    -- Disable love for the custom scenarios
    local love = nil
    scenario()
end
```

I have expected that the `scenario.lua` will know about `game` variable but will not know about `love` one, however, when I try to execute this code it gives me the following error:

```
Error: love/scenario.lua:1: attempt to index global 'game' (a nil value)
```

So is there a way to hide some interface by providing a little subinterface to it? In this concrete example I want to provide the same functionality for drawing circles and `love.timer.sleep` as love2d does but nothing else.

Another question is why `scenario.lua` sees `local love = nil` but does not see `local game` variable, I find this a mutual eclusion.

Comment: On Lua 5.1 you can use `setfenv` on Lua > 5.1 i think you have to use argument for `load` function. Or rewrite scenario.lua file to accept environment as argument when call it

Comment: @moteus thank you for your comment, `setfenv` works for me. But what about the last question?

Comment: it can not see this `love` as well as `game`. Wrap them in table and pass as environment.